# iOS TableViewController in PopOver disappears after touching tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, popover

I am developing universal iOS app and try to achieve popover.
I have tried WYPopoverController and FPPopover but those 2 does the same issue.

I have simple UITableViewController having 10 cells putting a static text on each cell (just for a test).

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
     return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier     forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
    [label setText:@"test"];

    return cell;
}
```

and try to show this in popover.

Sample code to apply FPPopover is

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {
    PopOverTableViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PopOverTableViewController"];

    FPPopoverController *popOver = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:vc];

    [popOver presentPopoverFromView:sender];
}
```

This shows text in 10 cells at a button tap but once I scroll inside of tableview,
the texts disappear and non of tableview data source methods are called afterwards.

It happened for both WYPopoverController and FPPopover so I am assuming there is something wrong in my side.
However, I could not figure out where I went wrong.

I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: it is the default behaviour of popover , it will be dismiss automatically if you click outside the popover . these are the two lines from documanation "The UIPopoverController class is used to manage the presentation of content in a popover. You use popovers to present information temporarily. The popover content is layered on top of your existing content and the background is dimmed automatically. The popover remains visible until the user taps outside of the popover window or you explicitly dismiss it. Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you guys for answering my question.
I solved myself.  It was due to having FPPopoverController as in local variable.  I needed to put as instance variable with strong property, otherwise the controller is deallocated by ARC.  That made a popover frame is still visible but table view content inside of popover is dismissed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this... was having a massive headache though :D

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what FFPopoverController does but in case of a normal popover controller you can use popover delegate method "popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover" to restrict the disappearance of a popover like following:

```
-(BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    return NO;
}
```

Surely, you need to declare UIPopoverControllerDelegate to the .h file of your view controller and set the "delegate" property of the popover controller to "self", for the above method to work.