# Data disappears from UITableView upon touch and release

Tags: ios, uitableview

UITableView data disappears on touch, as per screen shots below

The data loads correctly when the view is first loaded, like so.

[image: Before touch]

On touching the screen and then releasing, the data disappears. (If I touch and hold, the data is still present.)

[image: After touch]

I set a breakpoint in the UITableView custom class and noticed that the methods within (such as `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) are called when the view is loaded, but not after touch. The `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method is never called.

The code is very similar to the [DateCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html) example. I'm trying to load a DatePicker (configured to show time only) when a cell is touched.

The relevant code is below, along with a screenshot of the IB delegate and datasource connections. Please let me know if you need any more info. I am new to iOS, so I would greatly appreciate as much detail of possible causes and solutions as possible.

```
@interface ScheduleTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *timePickerIndexPath;
@property (assign) NSInteger pickerCellRowHeight;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *pickerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton; //to be used later for ios 6 compatability

@end



@implementation ScheduleTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSMutableDictionary *itemOne = [[@{ kPeriodKey : @"     Tap a cell to change the survey time: " } mutableCopy ] autorelease];
NSMutableDictionary *itemTwo = [[@{ kPeriodKey : @"Morning Survey",
                                   kTimeKey  : [NSDate date] } mutableCopy] autorelease];
NSMutableDictionary *itemThree = [[@{ kPeriodKey : @"Evening Survey",
                                     kTimeKey  : [NSDate date] } mutableCopy] autorelease];
self.dataArray = @[itemOne, itemTwo, itemThree];

self.timeFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
[self.timeFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[self.timeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

UITableViewCell *pickerViewCellToCheck = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kTimePickerID];
self.pickerCellRowHeight = pickerViewCellToCheck.frame.size.height;

[self.tableView setDelegate:self];
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell.reuseIdentifier == kDayPeriodAndTimeCellID) {
    // todo check for ios < 7.0

    [self displayInlineTimePickerForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

} else {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

NSString *cellID = kDayPeriodAndTimeCellID;

if ([self indexPathHasPicker:indexPath]) {
    cellID = kTimePickerID;
}

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

NSInteger modelRow = indexPath.row;
if (self.timePickerIndexPath != nil && self.timePickerIndexPath.row < indexPath.row) {
    modelRow--;
}

NSDictionary *itemData = self.dataArray[modelRow];

if ([cellID isEqualToString:kDayPeriodAndTimeCellID]) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [itemData valueForKey:kPeriodKey];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.timeFormatter stringFromDate:[itemData valueForKey:kPeriodKey]];
}

return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if ([self hasInlineTimePicker]) {
    NSInteger numRows = self.dataArray.count;
    return ++numRows;
}

return self.dataArray.count;

}
```

I am adding to an existing application, so all of the existing UI is implemented in XIB files, however this table is implemented in a storyboard. Here is a screen shot of the delegate and datasource outlet connections.

[image]

Comment: where is your cellForRowAtIndexPath code? from what I see, it seems you are loading table data from autoreleased objects instead of retained ones.

Comment: just added `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code. I added the autorelease just recently after running analyze, which reported potential memory leaks for the item* variables. The same problem was present prior to adding autorelease.

Comment: if dequeueReusableCell fails to return a cell, you need to create the cell

Comment: @rocky that's not true for the method being used. If a class or nib is registered for the reuse identifier (including in a atoryboard) then the method used here will always return a cell. No need to check if nil and instatiate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide a little more context here, but I have a guess.  A UITableView needs a UITableViewDataSource to tell it what data should be in the cells. Do you hook that up in the XIB? If so, I don't see any of the methods implemented in your ScheduleTableViewController.

Make sure you implement that protocol and specifically the method "tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:".  This is where you actually configure the cells that appear in the table view.

It sounds like you created the prototype table cells in InterfaceBuilder.  For each prototype cell you created, make sure you set it's cell identifier in the properties inspector.  Then use this cell identifier to identify which cell you are configuring in the call to "tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:".

Comment: Just added the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I assumed that since the data is populating correctly initially, the dataSource was correctly configured (or am I way off base?). Correct, the prototype cells are built within storyboard. I double-checked the cell identifiers and they are configured correctly (the 'identifier' text box in interface builder matches that in the code for the two prototype cells that I have)

Comment: Every tableview must have a datasource.  Just creating the prototype cells does not cover this requirement.  The prototype cells are just the cells that the table will have ready for configuration by the datasource.  Still, the datasource has to be there to tell the table how many rows to display and how to configure each cell.

Comment: The `dataArray` property is meant to be the datasource. I load items into the array in `viewDidLoad` and extract from it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Is there an explicit way to configure it as the datasource? In any case, unfortunately the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is not called when a cell is touched.

Comment: The datasource has to be an object that implements the UITableViewDataSource protocol.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks. Yes, an object is a datasource if it implements `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods, which my class `ScheduleTableViewController` does.

Comment: It's not enough to implement the methods.  There are two other steps. (1) In your header for ScheduleTableViewController you need to put "@interface ScheduleTableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>", (2) then in Interface Builder control+click your tableView and connect the outlets for 'delegate' and 'datasource' to your ScheduleTableViewController. (edit: if ScheduleTableViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController then you don't need to declare those protocols in the header since UITableViewController already declares them)

Comment: I established the datasource and delegate connections as you suggested. And `ScheduleTableViewController` does inherit from `UITableViewController`. Still the same problem unfortunately. I've updated the original question with new screenshots and the IB outlet view in case that provides any useful info.

Comment: Just noticed in your InterfaceBuilder screenshot it seems like you have a UILabel as a subview of the UITableView (i.e. as a sibling to the table cells).  I haven't tried to replicate that but I don't think you actually want that label to be a SUBVIEW of the UITableView - perhaps you want it as a sibling view but below the table? This could be causing an issue for you.

Comment: Also, try simplifying your data array to be just regular NSString objects. And make sure that data is available in your data array on each call to 'cellForRowAtIndexPath:'. Those NSMutableDictionary declarations look a bit suspect... good luck!

Comment: It was definitely a memory management issue. The dataArray property (my model) was losing its value after the initial screen loaded. When a row was tapped, the table reloaded, but there was no data to add to the table, hence the empty rows. I refactored the code to enable ARC, and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your table data with the functions

```
numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView
tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section
```

Comment: just posted the code for `numberOfRowsInSection`. `numberOfSectionsInTableView` defaults to 1, equal to the number of sections I have, so I did not implement that function.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue (in swift). It was solved by putting an instance variable to my tableViewManager responsible for presenting tableView. Initially an instance of it was created and called from button action method. So it was deallocated by ARC and consequently tableView had disappeared when I was trying to interact with it.
Inspired by:  [iOS TableViewController in PopOver disappears after touching tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788624/ios-tableviewcontroller-in-popover-disappears-after-touching-tableview)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using SwipeMenuViewController (https://github.com/yysskk/SwipeMenuViewController)

and in each page there was a table view.
When I click the tabs it's switch the tables with no problem. but when I touched the table the data disappeared although
the table exists (I used background colours to check)

My solution was to hold a reference to the UIViewControllers return from the SwipeMenuViewController method:

func swipeMenuView(_ swipeMenuView: SwipeMenuView, viewControllerForPageAt index: Int) -> UIViewController {
viewControllers[index.description] = baseContactsTableViewController
        return baseContactsTableViewController
}